# Polars - Using pl.when for modification in 2 columns

Tags: python-polars

I have this dataframe with values in thousands and millions:

```
sample = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 6000, 7000, 2, 3, 8000, 4, 8000]})
shape: (8, 1)
┌──────┐
│ a    │
│ ---  │
│ i64  │
╞══════╡
│ 1    │
│ 6000 │
│ 7000 │
│ 2    │
│ 3    │
│ 8000 │
│ 4    │
│ 8000 │
└──────┘
```

My aim is to obtain this dataframe:

```
shape: (8, 1)
┌──────────────┐
│ a            │
│ ---          │
│ str          │
╞══════════════╡
│ 1.0 thousand │
│ 6.0 million  │
│ 7.0 million  │
│ 2.0 thousand │
│ 3.0 thousand │
│ 8.0 million  │
│ 4.0 thousand │
│ 8.0 million  │
└──────────────┘
```

I was able to obtain the desired result. However, I did use 2 with_columns and 2 pl.when. My question is if **is it possible to reduce to 1 with_column and 1 pl.when?** Obviously, focusing on efficiency. If there is another way or, for some reason, 2 pl.when is faster, I'm pretty fine with that.

I did see some solutions with map, but they were with fixed values. So I wasn't able to reproduce  pl.col("a")/1000 with map.

The code that gave me the result:

```
sample.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a") >= 1000)
    .then(" million")
    .otherwise(" thousand")
    .alias("string")
).with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a") >= 1000)
    .then(pl.col("a")/1000)
    .otherwise(pl.col("a"))
    .cast(pl.Utf8)
    + pl.col("string")
).drop("string")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the 2x `pl.when` approach is slightly faster if you have a sufficiently large amount of data.

You can put them into a single `.with_columns`

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("a") >= 1000).then(pl.col("a") / 1000).otherwise(pl.col("a"))
     .cast(pl.String)
   + pl.when(pl.col("a") >= 1000)
       .then(pl.lit(" million")) 
       .otherwise(pl.lit(" thousand"))
)
```

[@Luca's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814312/) reads much nicer though, and the time difference is negligible.

Comment: thanks for sharing this possibility and looking into the time differences. 

I know that Polars syntax often nudges you towards faster code, but I'm always curious to see the speed difference.
And see if there is any tradeoff between readability and speed

Comment: @Luca Yes, I too share that quriousity, it's always interesting to see the different approaches people come up with.

Comment: jqurious approach is ~20% faster than @Luca's and also ~30% faster than mine with 2 with_columns. Although I might prefer Luca's answer, I guess jquirious' answer is better suited for my question.
Thank you for both of you

Comment: It seems there is a bit of overhead when using `pl.format` - which itself uses `concat_str` internally. I wonder if it could be improved.

Comment: Your new edit with variables is quite different for me, took me some seconds to really understand. Somehow, I still prefer polars' way though, seems more readable to me

Answer (score 2):

one option is to use `pl.format`. Here is an example:

```
sample.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a") >= 1000)
    .then(pl.format("{} million", pl.col("a")/1000))
    .otherwise(pl.format("{} thousands", pl.col("a")))
)

shape: (10, 1)
┌──────────────┐
│ a            │
│ ---          │
│ str          │
╞══════════════╡
│ 1 thousands  │
│ 6.0 million  │
│ 7.0 million  │
│ 2 thousands  │
│ …            │
│ 4 thousands  │
│ 5 thousands  │
│ 9.0 million  │
│ 10.0 million │
└──────────────┘
```